# Установка image через Uri Xamain

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Есть приложение написанное на C# Xamarin (Android, IOS).
Необходимо показывать изображение которое распологается на сайте.

Код для вывода изображения (XAML)

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Image x:Name="Image1" 
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

    </StackLayout>
```

Код для определения значения Image1

```
Image1.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Xamarin-logo.svg/1200px-Xamarin-logo.svg.png"));
```

В параметрах Android реализация HttpClient установлено как "Управляемый".
Реализация SSL/TLS установлено как "Собственный TLS 1.2+.
В манифесте установлена галочка на требуемом разрешении - Internet

Но при всех этих действиях изображение на экран смартфона не выводится. 
Тестируется на Samsung SM-G975F (Android 9.0 - API 28).

Данное решение тестировалось на UWP и все отработало корректно. В чем может быть проблема? Может необходимо установить определенные разрешения?

Visual Studio 2019 C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный вид должен иметь XAML файл:

```
<Frame HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="#E7E7E7">
<Image x:Name="myImage" Aspect="Fill" />
</Frame>
```

Код для загрузки изображения должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var url = "https://url";//ссылка на изображение
var byteArray = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));
```